# Open static html page in angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular5

Say, we have another folder called help along with the index.html file of angular 5 app.

I would like place an help.html file in the help folder and open context specific links (using name attribute in anchor tags) from angular app.

**What i have tried** is added links to the sections of help file (help/help.html) in angular app wherever required.

**What is happening is**, path to that html file is considered as with in angular app and browser is redirecting to within angular app.

*how to open a static html file* or a static pdf file *from an angular app which is in the same folder of deployed location*...

Comment: Put the html in a component's template?

Comment: Can't you create a component of that html page and load dynamically?

Comment: Yes, using component is my plan B. But, would like to learn how to refer a static resource in angular . . .

Answer (score 6):

add your static html files in the same directory as your index.html file in angular app, and then add your static html pages name in ".angular-cli.json" file in "assets": [] attribute

Comment: Tip: **Angular needs to be restarted to watch your added files/folders**, so suppose I would add a folder in `src/` called model, it should be accessed with `localhost:4200/model/`. The `src/` path doesn't need to be included.